# a question of definite integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

1.$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+e^{-(x+\ln(u/(1-u)))/\tau}}\, du$$

2.$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-u^{2}/2}}{1+e^{-(x-u)/\tau}}\,du$$

please help me. I tried to use MATLAB but I failed. The background of the first one   is the expectation of gumbel-softmax.

Comment: Would you give me more hints?

Comment: The original one is a little wrong. I modified it. The new can be solved in the same way?

Comment: The question is better suited to MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/, and is likely to be closed here briefly.

Comment: I transfer it to MSE

Answer (score 1):

Neither integral has a closed form expression. For $\tau=1$ the first integral evaluates to
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+e^{-(x-\ln(-\ln u))}}\, du=-e^{x+e^x} \text{Ei}\left(-e^x\right).$$

Comment: I think the second doesn't diverge because it is smaller than the integral of normal distribution.

Comment: you can take the $e^{-x^2/2}$ in the numerator out of the integral, since it does not depend on $u$, and then you can change variables from $x-u$ to $y$, so the integral you are evaluating is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty(1+e^{-y/\tau})^{-1}dy$ which diverges no matter what the sign is of $\tau$.

Comment: I am sorry that I made a mistake. I revised my question. Please help me.